# Commit HttpServletResponse without output anything

Tags: java, servlets, web

I'm working on a web project(java + jsp). In my project there is a download function, which will call HttpServletResponse.getOutputStream() to write into a output stream and download the file. And afterwards I can call outputStream.flush() to commit the HttpServletResonse, and then the page stop loading.

In another module I want the same behavior: stop loading the page. I can do it with the following code:

```
OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
out.write(1);
out.flush();
out.close();
```

the whole page stops loading but one file(the "1") will be download. That is not what I want. I want nothing to be download. So I tried:

```
OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
out.flush();
out.close();
```

But in this case the page-loading didn't stop at out.flush(), but at out.close(), and the worst thing is the whole page turn blank. I'm a noob for web programming, and I really don't understand what is happening. Could anyone explain this to me? And what I want is the page stop loading but doesn't turn blank and doesn't download anything. Thank you!

Comment: The browser has sent a request. The server then provides a response. If you return nothing, then nothing is displayed. This seems like an XY problem - what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: If you mark the response as a file, and you write nothing back, then what is returned is an empty file. You need to remove the header indicating that file "1" is being sent back.

Comment: @BoristheSpider In my project, If the whole process is gone through, then the page will be refreshed. That is not what I want for some module. So I want to commit the response before coming to the "Refreshing" code. But I've no idea the right way to do it. Every time downloading a 1 kb file is not a good choice.... I want to send the response without downloading anything. Thank you

Comment: @christopher Thank you man, but I'm a noob for these stuff. I'm not quite understand what you said. You meant that I use outputstream to commit the response, so I have to download something right? And what is the best way to commit the response?? Without any behavior, just commit the response and the browser won't get anything about the remaining code.

Comment: You keep using this word "download", but that is a concept that is one level above what you're attempting. In your `HttpServletResponse` you're setting the response type to multipart-file or something (I don't remember the correct name). When you *write* nothing to the output stream, it will still think it is a file, just an empty one. So what you need to do is make sure that the file header isn't being set in the `HttpServletResponse`.

Comment: If you want to prevent page refresh, consider sending an ajax request. For a normal http request, as previously pointed out in other responses, you have to send back something (html or a file). You will receive a blank page otherwise.